# Stripe: Must provide source or customer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe for my shopping cart project. I can't get my checkout form to submit. I keep getting this error message: "Must provide source or customer." Either I didn't set up my Stripe account correctly or I'm missing some parameters in my javascript. I've spent hours on this problem and still can't figure it out.

This is from Stripe's log:
**Parsed Request POST Body**

```
{
  "amount": "21000",
  "currency": "usd",
  "description": "Test Charge"
}
```

**Response Body**

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Must provide source or customer."
  }
}
```

**This is my app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var validator = require('express-validator');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

var app = express();

mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/shopping');
require('./config/passport');

// view engine setup
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(validator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysupersecret', 
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
    cookie: { maxAge: 180 * 60 * 1000 }
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});

app.use('/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**This is my index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Cart = require('../models/cart');

var Product = require('../models/product');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var successMsg = req.flash('success')[0];
    Product.find(function(err, docs) {
        var productChunks = [];
        var chunkSize = 3;
        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
            productChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
        }
        res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products: productChunks, successMsg: successMsg, noMessages: !successMsg});
    });
});

router.get('/add-to-cart/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var productId = req.params.id;
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});

    Product.findById(productId, function(err, product){
        if (err) {
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
        cart.add(product, product.id);
        req.session.cart = cart;
        console.log(req.session.cart);
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

router.get('/shopping-cart', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.cart) {
        return res.render('shop/shopping-cart', {products: null});
    }
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    res.render('shop/shopping-cart', {products: cart.generateArray(), totalPrice: cart.totalPrice});
});

router.get('/checkout', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.cart) {
        return res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
    }
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    var errMsg = req.flash('error')[0];
    res.render('shop/checkout', {total: cart.totalPrice, errMsg: errMsg, noError: !errMsg});
});

router.post('/checkout', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.cart) {
        return res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
    }
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    var stripe = require("stripe")(
      "**hidden**"
    );

    stripe.charges.create({
      amount: cart.totalPrice * 100,
      currency: "usd",
      source: req.body.stripeToken,
      description: "Test Charge"
    }, function(err, charge) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', err.message);
            return res.redirect('/checkout');
        }
        req.flash('success', 'Successfully bought product!');
        req.cart = null;
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**This is my checkout.js:**

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('**hidden**');

var $form = $('checkout-form');

$form.submit(function(event) {
    $('#charge-errors').addClass('hidden');
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
    Stripe.card.createToken({
      number: $('#card-number').val(),
      cvc: $('#card-cvc').val(),
      exp_month: $('#card-expiry-month').val(),
      exp_year: $('#card-expiry-year').val(),
      name: $('#card-name').val()
    }, stripeResponseHandler);
    return false;
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) { // Problem!

    // Show the errors on the form
    $('#charge-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $('#charge-errors').removeClass('hidden');
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

  } else { // Token was created!

    // Get the token ID:
    var token = response.id;

    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

    // Submit the form:
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

**This is my checkout form (.hbs):**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
    <h1>Checkout</h1>
    <h4>Your Total: ${{total}}</h4>
    <div id="charge-error" class="alert alert-danger {{# if noError}}hidden{{/if}}">
        {{errMsg}}
    </div>
    <form action="/checkout" method="post" id="checkout-form">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Address</label>
              <input type="text" id="address" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name on Card</label>
              <input type="text" id="card-name" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Credit Card Number</label>
              <input type="text" id="card-number" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Expiration Month</label>
              <input type="text" id="card-expiry-month" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Expiration Year</label>
              <input type="text" id="card-expiry-year" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">
              CVC</label>
              <input type="text" id="card-cvc" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Buy Now</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/checkout.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A payment flow with Stripe is divided in two steps:

1. Client-side, in your frontend code, you collect and tokenize the customer's payment information using [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements), then send the resulting token to your backend server.
2. Server-side, in your backend code, you use the token in an API request, e.g. to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) or [a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).

The code you shared is for the first step. However, the error message you mentioned:

> Must provide source or customer.

occurs in the second step. This error is returned by Stripe's API when you send a [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) without a [`source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-source) or [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-customer) parameter.

You need to check your server-side code to figure out what the problem is exactly. You can also check the logs of all requests sent by your integration in your dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs?method=not_get.

Comment: Thanks Ywain. I just updated my post with the server-side code (index.js) and also the error from Stripe's log. Not sure why it's saying I'm missing the customer parameter.  It's located in the stripe.charges.create code: 'source: req.body.stripeToken'.

Comment: Is `req.body.stripeToken` definitely being populated? It would indicate not if Stripe is not receiving it.

Comment: @vnguyen Have you configured `body-parser` in order to be able to decode and access the `stripeToken` parameter sent by your client-side form? Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12008719/5307473

Comment: @Ywain - updated the post again with my app.js code. Yes, body-parser is configured. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @vnguyen Okay, I think I found the issue -- it's in your client-side code. Try replacing `var $form = $('checkout-form');`  with `var $form = $('#checkout-form');`. Here's a modified version of your code that does create and post a token to the backend: https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/4rmf53x2/

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing < this helped out.

Answer (score 7):

So I emailed the Stripe support team for help on this issue a few days ago and finally got the solution.

The error was actually in the front-end side. I did not reference jquery under the checkout form. I was able to fix the whole thing by simply adding 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` before calling the checkout.js file. My checkout form works now.

Huge props to Stripe for going above and beyond with their support!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I was also referring to same video lectures as you and I encountered the same problem. I just made changes in the `/checkout` route(post request) in index.js file. Replace `source: req.body.stripeToken` with `source: "tok_mastercard"` and it worked for me, but I'm not sure about the reason behind this.

Comment: The reason is thats the test card's token and it will work in test mode. Plase check this link https://stripe.com/docs/testing

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the same video lecture, but changing to ***"tok_mastercard"*** worked for me

Comment: You may want to provide some context in your answer, maybe a code snippet of what you changed. Welcome to SO by the way!

Answer (score 0):

I added this `['source'=>$_REQUEST['stripeToken']` to my code and it worked for me. Previously I was using `['source' => 'tok_mastercard']`

`$stripe->customers->createSource( $stripecustomerid,['source'=>$_REQUEST['stripeToken']]);`