# Stripe: "Must provide source or customer"

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

PaymentController:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
public function paymentProcess()
{
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_1M123Dge214GicrsW30adwG12X1");
$token = $request->get('stripetoken');
$charge=\Stripe\Charge::create([
'amount'=>1000,
'currency'=>'usd',
'description'=>'Example charge',
'source'=>$token,
]);
}
}
```

index.blade.php:

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        Laravel + Stripe
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <form action="/api/payment" method="POST">
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
         data-key='pk_test_zWfsa5k3D21cq1hPA39FmIdMJfkG3Taf74LD'
        data-amount="100000"
         data-name="My Name"
          data-description="Test" 
          data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
        data-locale="auto" 
        data-currency="USD">
    </script>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

api.php:

```
Route::post('/payment','PaymentController@paymentProcess');
```

it keeps giving me this error Must provide source or customer. and on my stripe test dashboard its still 0, no money has been added. Any help is highly appreciated, Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey! Please have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500984/stripe-must-provide-source-or-customer

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help me

Comment: `stripetoken` or `stripeToken` ?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/issues/340

Comment: Iagbox i love you, stripetoken was the problem, needed to capitalize the T, to stripeToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input name that has the token is probably `stripeToken` not `stripetoken`.

```
$token = $request->input('stripeToken');
```